# Send a response from consumer to producer RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to send data from a server to several consumers. I have to decide when a message will be deleted from the queue so I want to implement that the consumers send a message to the server. If all the consumers send a response then I will remove the message.

I already found an RPC call but I think that is to complex for the problem I have. Is there a faster way to send a quick response to the server? I am using C#.

UPDATE: I think I already found a solution. I will notify the broker so it can be removed from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use prefetch to send multiple messages. The prefetch value is used to specify how many messages that are being sent to the consumer at the same time.

The client can send an ack back to the server, which will delete the message from the broker.

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to do. Thanks!